# почему не видит chromedriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "https://vk.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    login = driver.find_element_by_name_name("email")
    login.clear()
    login.send_keys("123")
    pswd = driver.find_element_by_name_name('pass')
    pswd.send_keys("123")
    but_log = driver.find_element_by_class_name("index_login_button")
    but_log.click()
main()
```

код выдаёт ошибку

```
      $ C:\py\piramida.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
      stdin=PIPE)
    File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\py\piramida.py", line 13, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\py\piramida.py", line 3, in main
      driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
      self.service.start()
    File "C:\Users\Danila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
      os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Все ведь написано в тексте ошибки: `Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`. `PATH` это переменная из переменных путей, либо указывайте в коде путь к драйверу, например: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f7b5f7562a86064e8c04fb62206af257efab7345/selenium__examples/hello_world.py#L26

Comment: Я понял,спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто следуйте инструкции в тексте самой ошибки:

> Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Т.е. [по указанной ссылке](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) скачайте драйвер и путь к нему (достаточно папки) добавьте в переменную среды `PATH`

Или же вручную укажите путь к драйверу [в классе через параметр executable_path](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d61cecb80ed6f5c24c4517f3255a8f787c7d366e/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#L34):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="<Путь до драйвера>")
```

Comment: а вы не знаете,что делать в случае,если я собираюсь перекинуть программу на компьютер другого человека?Я знаю,что у него есть Google Chrome,но chromedriver в переменной окружения PATH у него отсутствует,ручного доступа к его ПК у меня нет

Comment: Без `chromedriver` никак. Вы можете его в папке с программой держать, а в `executable_path` будет название `chromedriver`

Comment: понятно,спасибо