# Скрипт на selenium не видит chromedriver

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, chromedriver

В процессе переноса скрипта с heroku на сервер с ubuntu столкнулся с проблемой, что скрипт не видит chromedriver.

Итак. Устанавливал согласно [этой](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-selenium-v-linux#2) инструкции, однако вместо Chromium ставил обычный Chrome. Также нашел тут [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062920/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-chromedriver), но ответ не помог.

Посмотрел, что есть в PATH и засунул туда chromedriver.

Пруфы:

```
(venv) root@ip-172-31-39-163:/home/sla-for-anton-bot# echo $PATH
/home/sla-for-anton-bot/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

(venv) root@ip-172-31-39-163:/home/sla-for-anton-bot# find / -name chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
/usr/bin/chromedriver
/home/sla-for-anton-bot/chromedriver
```

Однако при выполнении выдает следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sla_parser.py", line 121, in <module>
    create_list()
  File "sla_parser.py", line 103, in create_list
    brw = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Собственно кусок кода:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

def create_list():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

#    brw = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    brw = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    brw.get(url)
```

Пути в `chrome_options.binary_location` и `brw = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=)` пробовал подставлять разные, в разные места PATH, где лежит драйвер, относительные, абсолютные, в виртуальном окружении, без него - все бесполезно.

Прошу совета, что и где я сделал не так.

Comment: 1. Попробуйте запустить без опций, brw = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver') 2. Попробуйте запустить в терминале /usr/bin/chromedriver

Comment: Без опций также пробовал - не работает.
При попытке запустить в терминале - `No such file or directory`

Comment: Может этого файла там и правда нет?  3. А зачем вы делаете os.environ.get('/usr/bin/chromedriver'), у вас разве есть переменная окружения '/usr/bin/chromedriver'? Вам нужно указать путь chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

Comment: @rusnasonov
Пробовал результат тот же. Файл на месте.
`(venv) root@ip-172-31-39-163:/home/sla-for-anton-bot# find ./ -name chromedriver
./chromedriver`

`(venv) root@ip-172-31-39-163:/home/sla-for-anton-bot# ./chromedriver
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: уже понятнее) попробуйте установить пакет apt-get update && apt-get install libgconf-2-4

Comment: @rusnasonov Хвала небесам, теперь он его нашел и запускается. Спасибо. Правда дальше все крашится, но это вероятно тема отдельного вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в отсутствующей библиотеке `libgconf-2-4`. Шаги по обнаружению проблемы.

1. Смотрим на ошибку, понимаем что драйвер запускается, но падает с какой-то ошибкой  `Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127`
2. Запустить драйвер без опций
3. Запустить из терминала `/usr/bin/chromedriver` и увидеть более подробную ошибку `error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4`
4. Установить библиотеку `apt-get update && apt-get install libgconf-2-4`