# пайчарм не видит веб драйвер

Tags: python, selenium

```
from instapy import InstaPy
import selenium
import instapy_chromedriver
from instapy import smart_run
from selenium import webdriver
insta_username = ''
insta_password = ''
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=False)
with smart_run(session):
    session.unfollow_users(amount= 5, instapy_followed_enabled=True, instapy_followed_param="all", style="RANDOM",
                           unfollow_after=48 * 60 * 60, sleep_delay=600)
```

- код
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибка вылазит вот такая, хоть вебдрайвер установлен в питоне
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062920/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-chromedriver?rq=1

Comment: не помогло, уже целый день с этим приколом долблюсь